# Show average (⌀) in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a formatter parameter like:

```
$P{FORMATTER} = "#,##0.00"
```

I want to print the average value at the end of a table with the specified sign in front:

```
'⌀' + $P{FORMATTER}
```

But all I get is a square

[image]

Any ideas why It isn't displayed correctly?

Comment: What is output format? pdf?

Comment: It's in a java preview window. When I export it to PDF the square is gone and just the number stays.

Comment: Are you using font extension mechanism? What font are you using?

Comment: I just use the standard "SansSerif"

Comment: What it JSS? I tried other unicode characters and they work.

Comment: Jaspersoft Studio

Comment: I can't preview it there but when I open the jrxml with the text editor i see: <patternExpression><![CDATA['âŒ€' + $P{FORMATTER}]]></patternExpression> which looks weird